# How can I run my haskell functions through Java

Tags: java, haskell

Lets say I have a haskell function **add** in **math.hs**

How can I run the **add** function through a Java program and store the output as a variable?

Maybe something like the following:

```
public int runHaskell(String haskellFile) {
    int output;
    //run add function from file 'math.hs' and store result to output
    return output;
}
```

( If required I also have access to the object file: *math.o* and the interpreter file *math.hi* as well as the executable *main.exe*. )

Comment: This might involve some clever tricks with JNI.  I'm curious to see what the answer is.

Comment: @templatetypedef I don't see how this would be any different than using JNI with C (GHC can generate intermediate C code)

Comment: @Rafe Kettler- True, but the naming conventions required by JNI and the fact that all the arguments have to be specific types would probably require you to build a "trampoline" C library that would then get linked in with the Haskell code.

Comment: If you need just a small portion of Haskell code, you might consider translating it to Jaskell ( http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JASKELL/Home )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy (but clumsy) way:

[`Runtime.exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Then you can listen to the output of the Haskell program, and then parse it for the result.

Alternatively, you can write a small wrapper for JNI that calls directly into your Haskell stuff.

Comment: Hmm. How do I listen for the output after I use exec() on the executable haskell program?

Comment: @Nick: `exec` returns a `Process` object, which you can use to get the stream that the process writes its output to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some of RPC frameworks, for example, [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift), which supports C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, Smalltalk, and OCaml.

There's also [BERT-RPC](http://bert-rpc.org) [client and server library for Haskell](http://github.com/mariusaeriksen/bert), but I'm not sure a Java port exists.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Interfacing_other_languages. There is also [Jaskell](http://jaskell.codehaus.org/) which might be able to run your entire source code under the JVM, allowing you to easily interface.